# Tag clouds: Are there any in either flash or javascript

Tags: javascript, flash

I would like to display tagcloud in my home page. Found this wordpress flash plugin http://alexisyes.com/tags/wpcumulus , but for that i needed to setup wordpress. I am wondering whether there is any other standalone plugin similar to wpcumulus which can be configurable.

I don't want to install wordpress but i would like to make use of wpcumulus. Is it possible? If not wpcumulus, could i make use of any other standalone tag clouds.

Just curious, i came across all tag clouds which were implemented in either flash or flex. Can i get the demo link/plugin which has implemented the same in javascript.

Thanks,
~shafi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could definitely use wpcumulus (I just downloaded it and checked it out). You just have to figure out what data it needs to create a tag cloud.

First, you need to download the swf and add it to your site. You can take a look of an installed version / demo of it to see the proper swf embed html.

Next, you have to figure out how it gets its data. The quickest way I think to do this is to go to a demo of wpcumulus and look at the http requests / responses going on. I use the Live Http Headers plugin for Firefox for this. It will probably look for a xml file that's set in its swf embed code. I'm guessing the xml might look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tags>
    <tag name="Books" count="4" />
    <tag name="Magazines" count="20" />
    <!-- etc... -->
</tags>
```

Now you just need to create an xml file that includes that data. You could either make it a static xml file, or use php or asp.net to create a dynamic page that produces xml.

Answer (score 0):

In other words, I would like to have 'auto-refresh' functionality for the tag cloud. Can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Please download BlogCumulus.Net for BlogEngine.Net platform from [99atoms.com](http://www.99atoms.com/post/BlogCumulusNET-A-flash-based-tag-cloud.aspx). It will give you complete idea about how you can use it in .Net.
Similarly for PHP read this page about using it in [Drupal](http://alexisyes.com/2008/10/8/how-setup-wp-cumulus-drupal)

Actually you don't need to give it full xml file but a string of format:

```
<tags>
<a href="#" title="C#" style="..." class="..">C#</a>
.............
...............
</tags>
```

I think the size of the tag comes from class attribute in <a>.
You can use [swfobject.js](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to generate the mark-up for inserting the flash object into the page.